# method calling problem

Tags: objective-c, ios4, methods, call, declaration

i've got this method:

```
-(void)reportAchievementIdentifier: (NSString*) identifier percentComplete: (float) percent
```

now I want to call this method in another method like:

```
[self thisMethod];
```

But how can I do this with a method that has local declarations in it?

thank you

Comment: when my questions aren't answered the right way, i can't accept them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter if a method has local declarations in it, that's completely normal. Have you tried calling `[self thisMethod];`? Does it crash?

Comment: the variables "identifier" and "percent" are undeclared

Comment: So you want to access the `identifier` and `percent` vars in `thisMethod`? Just pass them as parameters.

Comment: i don't get it, i solved the problem otherwise. thank you very much